# Export parts of tex file separately

Tags: include, export

I'm writing a longer document and need this version, where everything is put together, and a few parts of the file in seperate pdfs. For example it might be that I need subsection 1.2 as a standalone pdf, so starting at the top of a page. I didn't find anything online. I have everything together in one file and would like to do something like call

```
\chapter{Chap 1}
\section{Sec 1}
Some text.
\export{<section 1>}
\section{Sec 2}
...
```

and then have the normal pdf and one, which only contains section 1 with correct numbering. I thought about splitting my file and then using another type of input, which ignores the preamble so that I can use the file on his own, but then the numbering doesn't work. It wouldn't be a problem, if the main file would have to look a bit weird like every chapter name on a seperate page or so.

As you have asked what I mean with correct numbering, I don't really need citation or other refs beside the chapter / section numbering. But in general I think about it as this:
If my document is

**Chapter 1**
Some text and cite 1 
*Section 1* 
more text and cite 2 
*Section 2* 
even more text and cite 3 and 4 
**Chapter 2** 
same as above

and I export section 2, than I'd expect to get exactly what is written in section 2 but without the rest, so

*Section 2* 
even more text and cite 3 and 4

Is this possible? I can't believe that I do not find something useful. This seems to be pretty standard.

Thanks in advance for every reply

Comment: What do you want to do with page numbers in references?

Comment: what do you mean by "correct" numbering? You can either have two documents both with section1 and combined as section 1 and 2, or you can have one document with section 1 and another with section 2, also for references, if you use hyperref do you need to turn internal link in to cross-document links?

Comment: I edited the post. Hope this makes it better to understand

Comment: Your use case is the standard `\include` use case, so you do need no extra package just  `\include{chapter1}` and `\include{chapter2}` then _after a full run_ add `\includeonly{chapter2}`

Comment: With `\includeonly` I have to do a seperate run for every document I need and have to rename the pdfs after the runs, right? If that's the case, then I do not like this method, but thanks for it. So whenever I change something, I have to do it all over again?